# Duplicate PHP Code Block

Tags: php, url, foreach, simple-html-dom

I get images from a specific url. with this script im able to display them on my website without any problems. the website i get the images from has more than one (about 200) pages that i need the images from.

I dont want to copy the block of PHP code manually and fill in the page number every time from 1 to 200. Is it possible to do it in one block?

Like: $html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/**1...to...200**');

```
   <?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/1');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
}

$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/2');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
}

$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/3');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: simple thing, use a loop counter variable to change page number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop like so:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++){
    $html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/'.$i);
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
    }
}
```

So now you have one block of code, that will execute 200 times.

It changes the page number by appending the value of  `$i` to the url, and every time the loop completes a round, the value of `$i` becomes `$i + 1`.

if you wish to start on a higher page number, you can just change the value of `$i = 1` to `$i = 2` or any other number, and you can change the `200` to whatever the max is for your case.

Comment: But this doesnt do a page 2 ..->.. n

Comment: @Martijn in his example he does page 1 ..->.. n which is why I've also kept it to that.

Answer (score 1):

First, store them in a database. You can(/should) download the images to your own server, or also store the uri to the image. You can use code like [FMashiro's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646062/2519416) for that, or something similar, but opening 200 pages and parsing their HTML takes forever. Every pageview.

And then you simply use the `LIMIT` functionallity in queries to create pages yourself.

*I recommend this method anyways, as this will be MUCH faster than parsing html every time someone opens this page. And you'll have sorting options and other pro's a database gives you.*

Comment: While this is true, it can quickly become a mess if the site you retrieve your data from changes the content of their pages regularly.

Comment: Exactly as messy as your answer, for fetching, as I suggest your code to do that ;) If the OP goes for the download version, all it takes is one fetch.

Comment: I only meant that storing another site's data on your own server is hard to manage as the site you (possibly illegally) download the content from may change their pages regularly. So keeping track of the latest data will just be incredibly hard if you wish to keep your server sane at least. You'll have loads of duplicate or outdated data.

Comment: If I download the image, then what does it matter what the other site does?

Comment: as far as I'm understanding, the OP wants to get the 200 images from another site and display them. It would seem silly to store images which aren't your own and that can change. That is, if you want the images to be accurate. IF the OP wants to always server the same ones then your answer is better.

Comment: Every pagehit, your code will open 200 pages AND parse all that html. It will will take ages, hog up all your  resources and some of the other site, which might block you for it.

Comment: But that is what OP wanted.

Comment: And as more experienced users, we should give valid code, not litterly "what OP wanted"

Answer (score 1):

There are many good solutions, on of them: try to make a loop from 1 to 200

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++){
    $html = file_get_html('http://example.com/page/'.$i);
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Every pagehit, your code will open 200 pages AND parse all that html. It will will take ages, hog up all your  resources and some of the other site, which might block you for it.

Comment: @Martijn absolutely you are right, its a horrible job to parse this number of pages, but he just asked for a way to loop over them, so my answer is based on the question req. :)

Comment: Haha indeed, but I don't think OP even though this far ahead

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
function SendHtml($httpline) {
    $html = file_get_html($httpline);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo '<img src="'.$element->src.'"/>';
}
}


for ($x = 1; $x <= 200; $x++) {
 $httpline="http://example.com/page/";
 $httpline.=$x;
 SendHtml($httpline);
}

?>
```

Just loop. Create a sending function and loop to make the calls.
I recommend you to read all php docu in https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: Great example. Re usable too.

Comment: Could use some formatting, and you should probably just add the increment variable to the definition of `$httpline`  instead of making it a second line and concatenating there for readability.

Comment: @FMashiro no doubt you are correct, but, for a person that does not know how to do a loop, I´m trying to be an easy teacher, that´s also the reason for the link to w3schools =)

Comment: Every pagehit, your code will open 200 pages AND parse all that html. It will will take ages, hog up all your  resources and some of the other site, which might block you for it.

Comment: @Martijn thats not part of the question. I like your approach, but, as I stated before, if user is asking in php and does not know how to use a loop, aren´t you a little bit forward?